# $\lim_{z \to \infty} \text{Re}(z)=0$ imply that $\text{Re}(z)$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I show that $\lim_{z \to \infty} \text{Re}(z)=0$ imply that $\text{Re}(z)$ is bounded?

I know this seems obvious from definition of convergence, but I am having a hard time justifying it.

Comment: What is your definition of bounded? And how is it possible to take $z \to \infty$ but have $\text{Re}(z)$ be zero? Maybe I'm misunderstanding notation?

Comment: @paulinho Bounded definition is the same as real analysis. I have no idea about your second question.

Comment: Could you instead be referring to a sequence of numbers $\{z_n\}$? And instead you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \text{Re}(z_n) = 0 \implies \{\text{Re}(z_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of limit as $z\to\infty$, we have that $-1<\Re z<1$ outside of some closed ball $\Delta$. Also, $\Re z$ is bounded on $\Delta$. Therefore, $$\min\left\{-1,\, \inf_{z\in\Delta}\Re z\right\} \le \Re w\le \max\left\{1,\,\sup_{z\in\Delta}\Re z\right\} $$

for all $w\in \Bbb C$.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\text{Re }z$ is bounded?